# Why is my WPF ListView column not right aligning?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, alignment, text-alignment

In my `Explorer` view that displays a list of files, I have tried right-aligning the `Size` column as follows. I have the following resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:FileSizeConverter x:Key="FileSizeConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SizeTemplate">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource FileSizeConverter}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

`FileSizeConverter` is just an `IValueConverter` that converts numeric file sizes into string format with B, KB, MB etc. I then have the following column:

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource SizeTemplate}" Header="Size" Width="80" />
```

This displays the file size correctly converted, e.g. `8,2 KB`, but still left-aligned. I have followed the example in the Microsoft Docs article [How to: Change the Horizontal Alignment of a Column in a ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-change-the-horizontal-alignment-of-a-column-in-a-listview), so what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There are several complications here.
If you run Snoop and take a look at what you end up with in your view you'll find the textblock is hosted in a gridviewrowpresenter.
This is applying a bunch of code to lay out it's contents.
If you really want to know exactly how that works then you could pick through the source code here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewRowPresenter.cs

If you're more interested in how to get this to work as you want then there are two things to do:

1) Make the columns stretch:

```
<ListView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

2) Either put the textblock in a container that can fill that space and allow the textblock to align right. Or, more simply.  Set TextAlignment on your textblock.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SizeTemplate">
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right"
```

Comment: I already have what you suggest in 1) and 2), and it doesn't work. So if there's time I guess I go exploring the source code. If there isn't time, it's not too serious to leave a string formatted size (`FileSizeConverter`) left aligned. It's still more readable than just a long string of digits.

Comment: Look again. Textalignment is not in your markup and mine definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

To right align the text in a ListView GridViewColumn:

1. Set the ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" so the column cells inherit it
2. Set up a CellTemplate for the column you want to right-align with a TextBlock with its HorizontalAlignment="Right"
3. You can't use DataMemberBinding on the column, otherwise the CellTemplate will be ignored

For example:

```
<ListView Name="_priceListListView" ItemsSource="{Binding PriceList}" >

  <!-- How to set ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" -->
  <ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.Resources>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>

        <!-- Left-aligned text column -->
        <GridViewColumn Header="Item" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item}" />

        <!-- Right-aligned numeric column -->
        <GridViewColumn Header="Price" >
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```